# Bootstrap change max height of collapsible nav

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I'm making a mobile webb application, where a user would be able to buy meat and choose how much, and I would like to make a collapsable table which would be fixed at bottom. The code bellow works perfectly, untill I add more items, then the collapse button is unclickable because of the table being so big.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<footer class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tablecol">
        <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
    </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="tablecol">
    <div class="table-responsive bg-light" id="table">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Meat</td>
            <td>2 kg</td>
            <td>100 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

I have tried to apply `max-height` to footer but that didn't work. How to I apply `max-height` to the collapsible content and make it scrollable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can overflow container (`#table`) and apply `max-height`. Optional can make thead fixed.

```css
#table {
  overflow-y: auto;
  max-height: 200px;
}

th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background: white;
  z-index: 5;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
<footer class="navbar fixed-bottom navbar-expand-sm navbar-dark bg-dark">
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#tablecol">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="tablecol">
    <div class="table-responsive bg-light" id="table">
      <table class="table table-hover">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Amount</th>
            <th>Cost</th>
            <th></th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr>
            <td>Meat</td>
            <td>2 kg</td>
            <td>100 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td>Cheese</td>
            <td>1 kg</td>
            <td>200 kr</td>
            <td>&times;</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```